# resize small images without pixelation in php

Tags: php, image-processing, resize

I'm working on a PHP project where I need to resize images before storing them, I'm using this tool "Oberto/php-image-magician" [https://github.com/Oberto/php-image-magician].

The problem is that resizing small images to higher dimensions results in very bad pixelation, so i want to resize images by adding some dummy black area around the image (like facebook) not through the default resize algorithm, is there any useful plugin or naive algorithm for doing this?

example
source img: 
http: //www.mediafire.com/convkey/c81e/1eheaa31t8zg0c7zg.jpg?size_id=3

what "Oberto/php-image-magician" makes:
http: //www.mediafire.com/convkey/c361/jsgc56ji2mw7414zg.jpg?size_id=4

what i want:
http: //www.mediafire.com/convkey/988e/8dd31zcvdqzjoc7zg.jpg?size_id=4

thanks in advance

Comment: If you are just looking to basically add a large black frame then you don't need to resize. Just create a 500x500 px black picture and overlay your small picture on top of it.

Comment: thanks for your comment but that won't rock in all situations, say you have a 200X200 image and the target dimensions are 300X100

Comment: Yes it will, if you create the black image in PHP dynamically based on the image you will be placing on top of it. I never said to create it in paint. You will need to calculate the dimensions and create the black image dynamically.

Comment: ok
I have that 200X200 image
I'll create a black image dynamically with dimensions of 300X100 (Indeed, having the result to be 300X100 is a must)
How can I overlay the first one on the second one without cropping some part of it

Comment: i found a solution based on this [commented to the answer], but at the end, i'll use a static image created with paint :P :D, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php

As Monkey Zeus pointed out, just create a background image and then overlay your source image.

Comment: this is not what I'm looking for, the target destination dimensions are static (it never change, always 400X300, what if I have an image of 500X200, or 300X500 [i.e. some dimension is higher than what is targeted])

Comment: i figured out a solutions based on your comments 

--> check if both w and h of the image is smaller than 500X200
    :use your solution
--> else if both w and h of the image is higher than 500X200
    :that's cool, no pixelation will occur after resize:D
--> if any of the dimensions is higher
    :resize the exceeding dimensions [keeping aspect ration], and then use your solution